# Programmatically `git status` with dulwich

Tags: dulwich

I'm wondering how I can perform the equivalent of `git status` with dulwich?

## I tried this:

After adding/changing/renaming some files and staging them for commit, this is what I've tried doing:

```
from dulwich.repo  import Repo
from dulwich.index import changes_from_tree
r = Repo('my-git-repo')
index = r.open_index()
changes = index.changes_from_tree(r.object_store, r['HEAD'].tree)
```

Outputs the following:

```
>>> list(changes)
(('Makefile', None), (33188, None), ('9b20...', None))
(('test/README.txt', 'test/README.txt'), (33188, 33188), ('484b...', '4f89...'))
((None, 'Makefile.mk'), (None, 33188), (None, '9b20...'))
((None, 'TEST.txt'), (None, 33188), (None, '2a02...'))
```

But this output requires that I further process it to detect:

1. I modified `README.txt`.
2. I renamed `Makefile` to `Makefile.mk`.
3. I added `TEST.txt` to the repository.

The functions in `dulwich.diff_tree` provide a much nicer interface to tree changes... is this not possible before actually committing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [`dulwich.diff_tree.tree_changes`](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/8c359048216e79753165acff338bb73d727cee1e/dulwich/diff_tree.py#L162) to detect the changes between two trees.

One of the requirements for this is that you add the relevant tree objects to the object store - you can use `dulwich.index.commit_index` for this.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, a working sample:

```
from dulwich.repo import Repo
from dulwich.diff_tree import tree_changes

repo = Repo("./") 

index = repo.open_index()

try:
    head_tree = repo.head().tree
except KeyError: # in case of empty tree
    head_tree = dulwich.objects.Tree()

changes = list(tree_changes(repo, head_tree, index.commit(repo.object_store)))


for change in changes:
    print "%s: %s"%(change.type,change.new.path)
```

Comment: It appears not to be working since `repo.head()` is of type `str` hence you can't apply `.tree` on it :(

Comment: Appears to be more several api changes. There is now a `dulwich.porcelain.get_tree_changes(repo)` -- "Return add/delete/modify changes to tree by comparing index to HEAD." @Mapio